# How do I pass environment configuration like URLs to Flutter application using Jenkins?

Tags: flutter, dart, jenkins, devops

I have a Jenkins job that builds my Flutter application based on different parameters like flavor (for different environments), backend URLs, etc. Right now in the build phase, I have a bash script that creates a new dart file based on my parameters and then Flutter uses that file as its environment configuration.

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  final config = {
    'param1': Platform.environment['param1'],
  };

  final filename = 'lib/env.dart';
  await File(filename)
      .writeAsString('final environment = ${json.encode(config)};');
}
```

Is there a better way to send parameters like URLs from Jenkins to the Flutter application during the build process?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must try pass your URLs with environments variables from jenkins to flask app.

In **jenkins** for example you can create a build stage like this

```
stage('Build') {
      agent {
          label 'master'
      }
      environment {
          YOUR_URL = "https://example.com/api/v1"
      }
      steps {
          script {
              /* Some actions */
          }
      }
 }
```

So, in your flask app only just missing get the env variables with any method like os.environ method like this example

```
import os

YOUR_URL = os.environ.get("YOUR_URL")
```